# My React.js proyect with github pages is in black

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, github, github-pages

I made a project with React.js and published it on github pages, at start it was working fine, but after logging out and in a few times the screen was black, how can I fix it?

I already tried changing the "homepage", but that didn't work

Comment: this is the gh-page: https://watchmakker.github.io/NetflixClone/

Comment: Open the browser DevTools to see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: I guess you have achieved it somehow, because I can see the website populated

Answer (score 0):

In the dev console, I see 404 errors like this:
`https://watchmakker.github.io/static/js/main.5b0192f2.js`

But that url should be:
`https://watchmakker.github.io/NetflixClone/static/js/main.5b0192f2.js`